# Is there way to recover files ignored via .gitignore in the first commit?

Tags: git

I have a local repo. I made the mistake of adding a .gitignore file before the first commit with all the code. After adding the .gitignore file, the only files left in my repo are the ones that I wanted to ignore, that is the ones that matched my .gitignore file.

Tracing back the steps:

- I had a folder.
- I ran `git init .`
- I added a regular Python `.gitignore` file.
- I then commited adding the `.gitignore` file.
- After this, the only files left in my directory are those who my `.gitignore` file was supposed to be ignoring. Confusing?

Is there a way to recover the files which were ignored in the first commit of my repo?

Below is a screenshot after running `git reflog`

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: No. They were ignored, so they're not in git anywhere. There's literally nothing to recover, because they were never there in the first place.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know why the only files left in my repo were exactly those who were supposed to be ignored, instead of the ones that were not ignored?

Comment: What do you mean by "recover"? Aren't the files are still there? They are not deleted, right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You may need to explain your situation further.

Comment: I had a folder. I ran `git init .` I added a regular Python `.gitignore` file. I then commited adding the `.gitignore` file. After this, the only files left in my directory are those who my `.gitignore` file was supposed to be ignoring. Confusing?

Comment: If anything you've made it *less* clear. Are the files you think you've lost those that **were** or **were not** being ignored? What exactly did you do? What's the status now? Give a [mcve].

Comment: The files I lost were those who *were not* being ignored. This why I am stupefied.

Comment: You did something else other than add a `.gitignore` and committing, neither of which will spontaneously delete anything. And a `.gitignore` file can be added or modified at any time--adding/changing one and committing will never remove anything from your local directory. You did *something* to delete those files; whether or not they can be recovered depends on if they were ever under git and your system (e.g., how were they removed, do you have anything in place to just pseudo-remove files, etc)

Comment: Thanks Dave for the comment. I added a screenshot of the results from running `git reflog`

Comment: Please post text, not images of text. But I don't see how that information is helpful.

Comment: I clearly did not delete files *somehow* as you mention, otherwise it would show on the re-flog. If you don't think this is helpful, can you please provide constructive criticism instead of stating the obvious? Thanks again

Comment: Your reflog shows resets and commits--it doesn't show file activity. The point is that the steps you list cannot lead to files disappearing on their own (e.g., the `reset` you didn't mention). Simply looking at your shell history would provide the *actual* things you did.

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks for the help Dave!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the reflog output, my guess is that you ran `git reset --hard`, *after* a `git add` but *before* a `git commit`.  This would remove all the files you had added.  You *may* be able to recover their contents, but not their file names.

Here is an example:

```
$ mkdir treset
$ cd treset
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ..
$ echo '*.pyc' > .gitignore
$ git add .gitignore
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) bca0228] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
$ echo precious data 1 > file1
$ echo precious data 2 > file2
$ git add .
$ git reset --hard
HEAD is now at bca0228 initial
$ ls
$
```

As you can see, the precious data files are *gone!*

Their *data* are in now-unreferenced Git *blob objects*, which we can have Git discover and place into its `lost+found` directory:

```
$ git fsck --lost-found
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
dangling blob 683416f292727f4659d5efa59d068189cf1b43bc
dangling blob f9d4c4040845bb7db25db33ec455d9a0c6703e68
```

Now, to get the *content* back, we look inside the appropriate directory (you can see here I forgot to include `other/` in the initial `cd`), and inspect each file's content.  The files' *names* are lost—they were in the index that we reset with `git reset --hard`, and are not saved anywhere else, but if we remember that `precious data 1` means `file1` and so on, we can `mv` the files back:

```
$ cd .git/lost-found/
$ ls
other
$ cd other/
$ ls
683416f292727f4659d5efa59d068189cf1b43bc
f9d4c4040845bb7db25db33ec455d9a0c6703e68
$ cat 683416f292727f4659d5efa59d068189cf1b43bc 
precious data 1
$ cat f9d4c4040845bb7db25db33ec455d9a0c6703e68 
precious data 2
```

hence:

```
$ mv 683416f292727f4659d5efa59d068189cf1b43bc ../../../file1
$ mv f9d4c4040845bb7db25db33ec455d9a0c6703e68 ../../../file2
```

gets the files back where we want them, in the work-tree of the new repository (`path/to/treset` in my case).

Comment: You sir, deserve the highest of all high places of honor. I cannot thank you enough for your help! I opened a text editor in that folder and I am going one by one to recover what I needed!